# Question about memory

Tags: game-engine

A BGE question.

Writing this in order to ask if someone could confirm my confusion.
Lets say PC has 8GB ram and 1.5GB video card.
Lets say I've got a fair amount of stuff as assets stored on layer two.
And lets say some things increase rate of stuff being spawned or added into scene to a certain limited amount.

But which is the moment when stuff starts affecting memory of video card?
Is it already when the stuff is stored on layer two with the total data of the client and the map into which client is loaded into
or does it start affecting when the stuff is being spawned into the main scene where the action is going on?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a few tests, start your computer, open up your system monitor via Ctrl+Alt+Delete, or however you would on your OS, and then open a few scenes and see what impact it has on your system performance, e.g. what spikes most, GPU, Ram etc.

You could also look into using some resources from this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38560/gpu-usage-monitoring-cuda/78203#78203). It's specific to Linux, but I imagine NVIDIA, AMD, and Intel have similar options for the other OSes.